# Creating Number of Tab Fragments depends on Json Data

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

In my app,I am getting **Category data** from server. Depends on the **Category count** I need to create **Tab Fragment**.

If the Category count is 5,I need to create 5 Tab Fragment.

If 10 Category=10 Tab Fragment has to be created.

Even I do not have an idea to do this. Please help me to go ahead in my app.

Comment: Share your code here . Without that it's tough to understand what's your problem .

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149778/how-do-i-use-fragmentpageradapter-to-have-tabs-with-different-content)