# Tabs with different content in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android-fragments

I'm trying to create a Sign Up page, but if a user has already registered, then I want them to be able to swipe across to see the Sign In form instead.

Specifically, I'm trying to follow this Q&A: [How do I use FragmentPagerAdapter to have tabs with different content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149778/how-do-i-use-fragmentpageradapter-to-have-tabs-with-different-content) I've copied it all correctly, as far as I can see, but I'm having trouble with the part where the adapter instantiates the fragment.

In SignInActivity I have:

```
public class SignInActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    SignInPagerAdapter mSignInPagerAdapter;
    public List<String> fragments = new Vector<String>();
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        // Set up tabs and fragments
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.reg));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.sign_in));
        fragments.add(RegisterObjectFragment.class.getName());
        fragments.add(SignInObjectFragment.class.getName());

        mSignInPagerAdapter =
                new SignInPagerAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSignInPagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    private class SignInPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<String> fragmentsA;

        SignInPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentsA = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragmentsA.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.register);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.sign_in);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The layout activity_sign_in.xml contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then `RegisterObjectFragment` and `SignInObjectFragment` both extend Fragment and each have a corresponding layout.

The problem seems to be with this function in `SignInActivity`:

```
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragmentsA.get(i));
    }
```

At that point it's crashing out with the error:

```
RegisterObjectFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

It seems to be expecting a regular Fragment, but is getting the `RegisterObjectFragment` instead. Every example I can find has something along these lines, though - the function is supposed to return a Fragment, but instead is returning a user-generated extended Fragment. I've tried using some of the variations I've come across, but hit the same issue every time - it refuses to accept anything other than a Fragment.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - the problem was that the Fragment classes (RegisterObjectFragment and SignInObjectFragment) were extending android.app.Fragment, while the main class was using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

When I changed them all to support.v4, it started to work!

Leaving this here in case anyone else gets stuck on the same thing.